# Future Completer.future

Tags: dart, indexeddb

Could someone please explain to me what is wrong with the following code.
The line `.then((result) {window.alert("Record = ${oDbRec}");})` displays the following :

> Record = Instance of '_ThenFuture@0x2900bd4a'

What I want is the result from the `getObject()`. The code:

```dart
fHtmDisplayOneClient(String sKey) {
  var oDbRec;
  oDbRec = fDbSelectOneClient(sKey)
   .then((result) {window.alert("Record = ${oDbRec}");})
    ..catchError((oError) {window.alert("Error from fDbSelectOneClient. ${oError}");
    });
}
Future fDbSelectOneClient(String sKey) {
  var completer = new Completer();
  idb.Transaction oDbTxn      =   ogDb1.transaction(sgTblClient, 'readwrite');
  idb.ObjectStore oDbTable    =   oDbTxn.objectStore(sgTblClient); 
  idb.Request     oDbReqGet   =   oDbTable.getObject(sKey);
  oDbReqGet.onSuccess.first.then((val)  => completer.complete(oDbReqGet.result));
  oDbReqGet.onError.first.then((err)    => completer.completeError(err));
  return completer.future; // return the future
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want what the future returns, which is the 'result' object passed to .then()

```
.then((result) => print('$result'));
```

Comment: Tks, John - as obvious as it may appear.

Comment: No worries.  We've all been there. ;)